# UI Controls in .NET Interactive Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, f#-interactive

I'm plotting F# functions in a Jupyter Notebook on a .NET Interactive Kernel like this:

[Plotting F# function in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDt69.png)

I want to make this graph interactive so variables (and therefore the line of the graph) can be manipulated live. Is it possible to add a slider UI control with F#, like it can be done in Python with [ipywidgets](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib)?

Comment: Show us what you tried?